# How to delete history entries added through history.pushstate?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, browser-history

I want to totally remove some history entries added via `history.pushState` instead of using `history.replaceState` to modify them. How should I achieve this?

Comment: I think that would be a security flaw.

Answer (score 1):

Editing previous history entries is not possible. From the history documentation:

> All the getters and setters for attributes, and all the methods, defined on the History interface, when invoked on a History object associated with a Document that is not fully active, must throw a SecurityError exception

http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/history.html#the-history-interface